# Order of methods called using inheritance in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

The order in which the letters are printed is "ABDC" Why does it print the last letter C? I provided my thinking steps and guide in the comments in the code.

```
public class Base {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Base b = new Derived();
    b.methodOne();
}

public void methodOne() { //Step 1
    System.out.print("A"); //Print "A" first
    methodTwo();      //Sends me to Derived class's methodTwo()
    }

public void methodTwo() { //Step 3
    System.out.print("B");  //Print "B" second
}

}

public class Derived extends Base{

public void methodOne() {
    super.methodOne();
    System.out.print("C");
}

public void methodTwo(){     //Step 2
    super.methodTwo();       //Sends me to Base class's methodTwo()
    System.out.println("D"); //Step 3 Print "D"
}
```

}

Comment: Your step 1 is wrong. You have correctly identified that calling `methodTwo` goes to `Derived#methodTwo`. But what happens in `main` when you call `methodOne`? Which `methodOne` does it call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`methodOne` from `Derived` overrides  `methodOne` from `Base`.  That means that if you have an object of *class* `Derived` - that is, an object that was created as `new Derived()`; then when you call `methodOne()` on that object, you'll get the version of `methodOne` from `Derived` being called.  It doesn't make any difference what *type* of variable you call it *through*.

So in your example, when you write `b.methodOne()` in your `main` method - it doesn't matter that the *type* of the variable `b` is `Base`, what matters is that the variable refers to an object whose *class* is `Derived`.  And the version of `methodOne` in `Derived` prints `"C"`, after it's done everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Call sequence:

1. `main` construct instance of `Derived`
2. Derived.methodOne calls
3. super.methodOne == Base.methodOne calls
4. this.methodTwo == Derived.methodTwo calls
5. super.methodTwo = Base.methodTwo

Now you have to observe the order of calling other methods and `System.out.println` (in `Base`first print then call, in `Derived`the other way round).